# flickr api photos.search by tags or by text results show broken image

Tags: flickr

I have a question:
for some reason when I do search on flickr either by tags or by text and I receive the results , I try to show them as a small image on my html , although I receive 500 results about 1-3 of them are shown as a broken image the rest are fine.but when I click on the "broken image" it does send me over to the correct Image at the flickr site 
(every image is also a link to the original location in flickr.com and the link works well).
what can be the reason? is it a well known bug ?
Thanks
Mary

Comment: I wonder if your browser is timing out when trying to load images.. perhaps it waits N seconds then shows a broken-image icon if it hasn't connected yet? Which browser and version? How long does it take to render the ones that _do_ show up?

Comment: It would be a good idea to include in your question the section of your generated HTML that includes the broken images, so that people can check whether there's anything wrong with that.  (It may be that the URL in the `a` link is fine, but the URL in the `img` element has been mangled somehow.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a kludge, but if the images are not broken, you can attach an onError event to them and re-load them at that time.  It might provoke the broken ones to "fix" themselves.